# how to get the posiible combinations using matlab

Tags: matlab, data-mining

How can i get the possible combinations to get 20 'i's from the given vector:

```
dn = 0 i i i i i i i i i i i i 0 i 0 i i i i i i i 0 i i i i 0 i i i i i i i i i 0 0 i i i i i i i 0 i i i 0 i i 0 i i i 0 i 0 0 0 0 0 0 i i 0 0 0 0 0 0 i i 0 0 0 0 i i 0 0 0 i 0 i 0 0 i 0 i 0 i i 0 i i 0
```

My objective
1. No of possible combinations with each combination having 20 i
2. Index value of each 'i's for all combination

Example:

```
var = 0 i i 0 i 0 i i 0 0 0 i
```

Here I need posiible combinations with 2 'i's
I can form the combinations like `(2,3),(2,5),(3,5),(2,7)` and so on.

Comment: Though the language is rough, I can understand what the OP wants.  I disagree with the vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
var = [0 i i 0 i 0 i i 0 0 0 i];
N = 2;
result = nchoosek(find(var==i), N);
```

In your example, this gives

```
result =
     2     3
     2     5
     2     7
     2     8
     2    12
     3     5
     3     7
     3     8
     3    12
     5     7
     5     8
     5    12
     7     8
     7    12
     8    12
```

Comment: That's my interpretation as well +1.  It's too bad that other people decided to close it (non-MATLAB users) because we are in a position to be able to answer it and yet....

Comment: @rayryeng I must say I voted to close, but then I understood what the OP wanted and retracted my vote. Yes, the question is not well phrased, but one can get an idea what is being asked

Comment: I understand :) BTW, I now see why someone would want to vote it to close.  The first question asked for all possible 20-tuple combinations... yet the second example wants it for all pairs... what do they want!?